# Conditional expectation calculation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Is following equality true:
$$E[X_{1}X_{2}|X_{1}=2]=E[2X_{2}|X_{1}=2]$$

If no how to calculate/simplify this, assuming that we have joint density and marginal densities of those RV and they are not independent.

Also what is generally speaking:

$$E[X|X=x]$$??

Comment: $E[X_{1}X_{2}|X_{1}=2]=E[2X_{2}|X_{1}=2]$ is true and $E[X\mid X=x]=x.$ What is your question? Do you want to see a proof?

Comment: yes, thanks very much ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For discrete distributions**

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ take their values from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and let the common probability mass function be given: $P(X_1=i\cap X_2=j)$. Also, assume that $P(X_1=2)>0.$

By definition

$$E[X_1X_2 \mid X_2=2]=\sum_{u=1}^{n^2}\sum_{\{i,j\ :\  i\cdot j=u\}}uP(X_1=i\ \cap\ X_2=j\mid X_1=2)=$$
$$=\sum_{u=1}^{n^2}\sum_{\{i,j\ :\  i\cdot j=u\}}u\frac{P(X_1=i\ \cap\ X_2=j\ \cap X_1=2)}{P(X_1=2)}=$$
$$=\sum_{u=1}^{n^2}\sum_{\{j\ :\  2\cdot j=u\}}u\frac{P(X_1=2\ \cap\ X_2=j)}{P(X_1=2)}=$$
$$=\sum_{j=1}^n2jP(X_2=j\mid X_1=2)=E[2X_2\mid X_1=2].$$

---

$$E[X\mid X=x]=\sum_{i=1}^niP(X=i\mid X=x)=x.$$

Answer (score -1):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then the equality $\mathbb E[X_1 \cdot X_2 \mid X_1 = 2] = \mathbb E[2 X_2]$ is true and in this case we can plug $X_1 = 2$ in for $X_1$.

If we do not have this assumption of independence, more generally we have

$$
\mathbb E[X_1 \cdot X_2 \mid X_1 = 2] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x_1 \cdot 2 \; f_{X_1 X_2 \mid X_2} (x_1 x_2, 2) \; dx_1 = \mathbb E[2 X_2 \mid X_1 = 2]
$$

which is a proof

A source for this is: http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf

In general, $\mathbb E[X \mid X = x] = x$. Why? Well, consider the quantity $X \mid X = x.$ This is no longer a random variable, it is simply a constant $x$. Qualitatively, an example is, the expected value of a coin flip (0 for tails, 1 for heads), given that the coin flip already happened, is simply the outcome of the coin flip that already happened, which we can observe.

Comment: Right. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: "Well, consider the quantity $X \mid X = x.$" Sorry but I will not consider it, for the reason that the "object" $$Y\mid X=x$$ does not exist. Before this, relying on conditional PDFs to prove a property of conditional expectations is rather bizarre since, first, it is not needed and, second, conditional PDFs may not exist.